# Writing a Java QuickSort function with only 1 Array

Tags: java

I'm a CS student and for an assignment, my professor is allowing us to use code from QuickSort programs online and sync it up with a sort file in our project. I have the following complete:

```
public class QuickSort extends SortAlgorithm
{

        @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return "Quick Sort";
    }

        @Override
    public void sort(int[] data)
    {
            // Using code from: https://www.programcreek.com/2012/11/quicksort-array-in-java/
            // Making their code work with mine
            int[] arr = data;
            int start = data[0];
            int end = data[1];

            int partition = partition(arr, start, end);

            if(partition-1>start) {
                 quickSort(arr, start, partition - 1);
            }

            if(partition+1<end) {
                 quickSort(arr, partition + 1, end);
            }
        }

        public static int partition(int[] arr, int start, int end){
        int pivot = arr[end];

        for(int i=start; i<end; i++){
            if(arr[i]<pivot){
                int temp= arr[start];
                arr[start]=arr[i];
                arr[i]=temp;
                start++;
            }
        }

        int temp = arr[start];
        arr[start] = pivot;
        arr[end] = temp;

        return start;
        }  
}
```

My only question is how to change the

```
if(partition-1>start)
```

and

```
if(partition+1>start)
```

so that they work with the rest of the program. I am fine with recursion in the program, but the original code used parameters for Quicksort which I cannot use in mine. Any advice for how to fix it?

Edit: I ended up switching to a program which was slightly closer. Here is what I have so far:

```
@Override
    public void sort(int[] arr) {
            int left = arr[0];
            int right = arr[arr.length];

            quickSort(arr, left, right);

        }

        public void quickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right) {

        int pivotIndex = left + (right - left) / 2;
        int pivotValue = arr[pivotIndex];

        int i = left, j = right;

        while(i <= j) {

            while(arr[i] < pivotValue) {
                i++;
            }

            while(arr[j] > pivotValue) {
                j--;
            }

            if(i <= j) {
                int tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }

            if(left < i) {
                quickSort(arr, left, j);
            }

            if(right > i) {
                quickSort(arr, i, right);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see that correctly:

Your

```
public static int partitaion(int[] arr, int start, int end)
```

uses "int start" as a parameter which doesn´t get changed. Then you return this int and give it to "int partition".

After that you do your if statements:

Example:

```
int start = 1;
int partition = partition(arr, start, end);
// partition() returns start without a change
// if now replaced with the values
if ((1-1) > 1) { /* your code */ }
```

So essentially you will never get into the first if statement. I would suggest you dont copy the code and just google how Quicksort works. It really is simple if your pivot element is just the first of each small array.

I am sure you can do that by some kind of algorithm in the beginning that calculates the size of the array given by the numbers your original data has.

Example:

Your array consists of 10 elements

```
1 0 2 9 3 8 5 7 4 6
```

And they would be sorted like this:

```
1 0 2 9 3 8 5 7 4 6

0 1 2 9 3 8 5 7 4 6 // 1 sorted; 1 = pivot
  |
0 | 2 9 3 8 5 7 4 6 // 0 sorted; 0 = pivot... u get it
| |  
| | 2 9 3 8 5 7 4 6 // 2 sorted; 2 = pivot... u get it
| | |
| | | 3 8 5 7 4 6 9 // 9 sorted
| | |             |
| | | 3 8 5 7 4 6 | // 3 sorted
| | | |           |
| | | | 5 7 4 6 8 | // 8 sorted
| | | |         | |
| | | | 4 5 7 6 | | // 5 sorted
| | | |   |     | |
| | | | 4 | 7 6 | | // 4 sorted
| | | | | |     | |
| | | | | | 6 7 | | // 7 sorted
| | | | | |   | | | 
| | | | | | 6 | | | // 6 sorted
| | | | | | | | | |         
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 // all sorted
```

So in order for that to happen in one array you need 10 empty spaces and a seperator for every number or mini-array.

So:

```
{"","","","","","","","","","", "1","0","2","9","3","8","5","7","4","6"}
```

But you need a maximum of 11 seperator:

```
{"","","","","","","","","","", "","1","","0","","2","","9","","3","","8","","5","","7","","4","","6","",}
```

It´s totally up to you if you:

1. Understand what i mean
2. Really HAVE to do it in one array (without its way easier)
3. Can use my given information

Comment: I ended up switching to a different program which was closer to mine. I understand the basics of how Quicksort work, I just need help implementing it with 1 array (as that was the specific instruction given by my professor).